# How do I use SQL PIVOT for multiple aggregates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a source table that looks like the below:

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════════╗
║       Topic        ║     Person     ║ PersonsReply ║  PersonsComment  ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Is the earth flat? ║ This Person    ║ Yes          ║ It's flat.       ║
║ Is the earth flat? ║ That Person    ║ No           ║ It's round       ║
║ Is the earth flat? ║ Another Person ║ Maybe        ║ Don't care.      ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

But from the examples I've seen online, I can't seem to transform my data into a tabular representation like below:

```
╔════════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╦═════════════════════╦════════════════════╦════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║       Topic        ║ ThisPersonsReply ║ ThatPersonsReply ║ AnotherPersonsReply ║ ThisPersonsComment ║ ThatPersonsComment ║ AnotherPersonsComment ║
╠════════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬═════════════════════╬════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║ Is the earth flat? ║ Yes              ║ No               ║ Maybe               ║ It's flat          ║ It's round         ║ Don't care            ║
╚════════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╩═════════════════════╩════════════════════╩════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

How can I use SQL's PIVOT function for what I'm trying to achieve? Here is my sandbox: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e198d/1

Right now I'm getting:

```
topic   ThisReply   ThatReply   AnotherReply
Is the earth flat?  (null)  (null)  (null)
```

Comment: I am guessing you need a dynamic number of columns returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using conditional aggregation to pivot your dataset:

- this is a cross-database solution, so you just get to learn the technique once, and then you can use it anywhere
- it usually performs at least as good as vendor-specific implementations
- another advantage is that you can handle more complex aggregate expressions than when using `pivot` (which is not the case for your question, but might eventually come up)

Query:

```
select 
    topic,
    max(case when person = 'This person' then personsReply end) ThisPersonsReply,
    max(case when person = 'That person' then personsReply end) ThatPersonsReply,
    max(case when person = 'Another person' then personsReply end) AnotherPersonsReply,
    max(case when person = 'This person' then personsComment end) ThisPersonsComment,
    max(case when person = 'That person' then personsComment end) ThatPersonsComment,
    max(case when person = 'Another person' then personsComment end) AnotherPersonsComment
from ptest 
group by topic
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ce9db923aa55d7abf7accdc2dfe288fa)**:

```
topic              | ThisPersonsReply | ThatPersonsReply | AnotherPersonsReply | ThisPersonsComment | ThatPersonsComment | AnotherPersonsComment
:----------------- | :--------------- | :--------------- | :------------------ | :----------------- | :----------------- | :--------------------
Is the earth flat? | Yes              | No               | Maybe               | Its flat           | Its round          | Dont care
```

Comment: Thanks, I also think the conditional aggregation is the way to go. I used Yogesh's answer but this is the same. Much appreciated.

Comment: @DanielMinnaar: Welcome. Note that Yogesh's answer was posted sligthly after mine, and it has less explanation... any reason why you accepted their rather than mine?

Comment: Please elaborate on the downvote. What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: I didn’t downvote? I upvoted you and marked yours as the answer.

Comment: @DanielMinnaar: sure. The question was aimed at the downvoter themself...

Answer (score 2):

You want *conditional* aggregation :

```
select topic,
       max(case when Person = 'This' then reply end) as ThisPersonsReply,
       max(case when Person = 'That' then reply  end) as ThatPersonsReply,
       max(case when Person = 'Another' then reply  end) as AnotherPersonsReply,
       max(case when Person = 'This' then comment end) as ThisPersonsComment,
       max(case when Person = 'That' then comment end) as ThatPersonsComment,
       max(case when Person = 'Another' then comment end) as AnotherPersonsComment
from ptest pt
group by topic;
```

Here is [DB](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e198d/16) fiddle.

Comment: You're right - this is clean and works great, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a non-dynamic PIVOT, it becomes a small matter with a `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
SELECT  *
FROM (
    SELECT topic
          ,B.*
    FROM ptest
    Cross Apply (values (person+'Reply',reply)
                       ,(person+'Comment',comment)

                )B(Item,Value)
) AS source
PIVOT ( max(value) FOR item IN ([ThisReply], [ThatReply], [AnotherReply],[ThisComment], [ThatComment], [AnotherComment]) ) AS pivotTable
```

**Returns**

```
topic               ThisReply   ThatReply   AnotherReply    ThisComment ThatComment AnotherComment
Is the earth flat?  Yes         No          Maybe           Its flat    Its round   Dont care
```